# Why am I receiving this error :Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function?

Tags: jquery

Here is where the jquery libraries are loaded, in the Layout,

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-C6CB9UYIS9UJeqinPHWTHVqh/E1uhG5Twh+Y5qFQmYg="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
            integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is where it is used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#SampleDiv").dialog({
             modal: true
         });
     });
</script>
```

Now, I read up on JQuery.noConflict, but I can't get that to work and I don't know exactly where to put it.

Comment: If `$(document).ready` works then noConflict isn't the issue/solution.  You're not including multiple versions of jquery on your page, are you?

Comment: I have included multiple versions or JQuery, not JQuery-UI

Comment: I am sorry I am not following?

Comment: well don't they have different purposes? I can try to get rid the top one

Comment: Okay what suggestions do you have?

Comment: Only use one version and keep that one above jquery-ui

Comment: I removed JQuery-UI and I am still getting the same issue

Comment: sorry for the confusion... I do not have multiple versions of Jquery.js

Comment: I had to comment out the following:  @*@@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@ and now it works

Answer (score -1):

Seems to work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#SampleDiv").dialog({
             modal: true
         });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-C6CB9UYIS9UJeqinPHWTHVqh/E1uhG5Twh+Y5qFQmYg="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
            integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="SampleDiv"></div>
```